# Angular 2 - trackBy function, what does it really do?

Tags: javascript, angular

I was under the impression that `trackBy` function is used only when trying to optimize the performance of `*ngFor`, so that if something changes, the DOM doesn't have to be rebuild.

However, recently, I came across a situation when `trackBy` actually fixed a wrong behavior.

Take this for example: https://plnkr.co/edit/nRgdwoiKAMpsbmWaoMoj?p=preview
Focus on **Hobbies** section, especially HTML:

```
<div>
  <h2>Hobbies</h2>
  <div *ngFor="let h of user.hobbies; trackBy:customTrackBy; let i = index">
    #{{i}} - {{h | json}}<br />

    <input [(ngModel)]="h.name" name="hobby_name_{{i}}" /> <br /><br />

    <select [(ngModel)]="h.type_id" name="type_{{i}}">
      <option *ngFor="let t of types" [value]="t.id">{{t.type}}</option>
    </select>

    <br />
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-warn" (click)="remove(i)">Remove</button>
    <br /><br />
  </div>
</div>
```

I had to explicitly define this part: `trackBy:customTrackBy` in the first `*ngFor`. If `trackBy` is removed, and the following steps are performed:

1. remove the first item
2. add a new item

In this case, the inputs of the first item get replaced with the content of the second item (both fields have the same content), however, the values in the model are correct.

`trackBy` solves this issue, but why?

I would really appreciate any kind of explanation. If this is not the right place to ask this kind of questions please redirect me to the correct one. Thanks.

**update**

Here's an example of the wrong behavior: https://plnkr.co/edit/u8YajKfHcPiVqY0WcJt7?p=preview remove the first item (cycling) and add a new item (add button) and see how both values get the same default value (BF will get replaced by "default value" even though the model stays correct).

Comment: In short: when you mutate an array, angular needs to know if an item was added, removed or only moved. Trackby helps angular to find back the item in the data model and deduce what happened. This is to prevent redrawing the whole array as you only added one item into the dom.

Answer (score 1):

`*ngFor` by default tracks items by object identity.

If you have primitive values like an array of strings, and use them in

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
  <input [(ngModel)]="item" name="item{{i}}">
</div>
```

and you edit one item, then `*ngFor` gets in trouble, because the identity of the edited item has changed.

With `ngForTrackBy` you can tell `*ngFor` to track the item by index, then above code will work fine when you edit fields.

Another use case is when you want `*ngFor` to track items by some custom object id property instead of the object identity.

Comment: Why specifically does it get in trouble? And in my case I don't have primitive values, but objects, so it should be fine I suppose, but it's not. Could you please address the HTML I provided in the post and why doesn't it work correctly when removing and adding items?

Comment: What exactly does "both fields have the same content" mean? I also don't understand what you expect "the inputs of the first item get replaced with the content of the second item". Isn't that the expected behavior when the first item is deleted, that the 2nd takes its place?

Comment: I guess I didn't explain myself well enough. I 've updated the question above, so: Here's an example of the wrong behavior: https://plnkr.co/edit/t5WF60RxVOR0yJVAUL9t?p=preview remove the first item (cycling) and add a new item (add button) and see how both values get the same default value (BF will get replaced by "default value" even though the model stays correct).

Comment: Sorry, but this is too much code. I don't have that much time.

Comment: I understand. I stripped the code to a minimum, so if you find the time later, here it is: https://plnkr.co/edit/u8YajKfHcPiVqY0WcJt7?p=preview

Comment: @uglycode I would say this is because you have a form, and you are using the index to differentiate the different form fields, so when you remove and add items, the index changes and messes up things. You can test it by removing the form tags it works just like you'd expect :)

Comment: that is true, it works. But I'd like to have form, of course. However, why does trackBy solve this problem then? trackBy doesn't have anything to do with the form fields, or does it?

Comment: Forms doesn't really care about the ngModel, but instead by the name attribute (therefore your model stays correct, but fields get wrong values in this case). Therefore you need to have unique names for form fields. So basically we could say that this "equals" the fact that your fields are of primitive type... `hobby_name_0`, `hobby_name_1` etc. Then when you edit, suddenly these "primitive" types change and ngFor is in trouble. Someone smarter can correct me if I'm wrong and probably explain this better ;)

Comment: Thanks for your input! I would just like to add that I've examined the HTML and the names of the fields are correctly re-assigned. I suppose that's why `trackBy` solves the issue?